# Python, iterating through an excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, for-loop

I need to write the program that loops through the columns of data. Resetting the variable based on the cell value and each column representing a variable.

The variables in the exercise are dependent on these values that are being looped through.

How can I loop through the rows with each iteration of the loop increasing the value by 1?

```
df=pd.DataFrame(r'C:/Users/user.name/Desktop/P_list.xlsx',sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
for i in range(0,5000):

    df2 = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/user.name/Desktop/P_list.xlsx',sheet_name = 'Sheet1'), index = list(range(i,5000,1), columns=list(range(0)))
    df3 = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/user.name/Desktop/P_list.xlsx',sheet_name = 'Sheet1'), index = list(range(i,5000,1), columns=list(range(1)))
    df4 = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/user.name/Desktop/P_list.xlsx',sheet_name = 'Sheet1'), index = list(range(i,5000,1), columns=list(range(2)))
    df5 = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/user.name/Desktop/P_list.xlsx',sheet_name = 'Sheet1'), index = list(range(i,5000,1), columns=list(range(3)))
    firstname = df2
    lastname = df3
    address = df4
    number= df5

#performed exercise
```

Comment: Idea is not cleat to me. What do you mean by saying `program needs to loop through the sheets of column's data`?

Comment: It needs to loop through the columns of data. Resetting the variable based on the cell value. Each column representing a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tried this on Jupyter. This is needed to load the Excel to `df`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
df = pd.read_excel('Sample.xlsx', sheet_name = 0)
```

Then looping towards the column names is like this:

```
for col in df.columns:
    print(col)
```

And looping towards the data is this:

```
for col in df.columns:
    print("NEW ROW ----------")
    for val in df[col]:
        print (val)
```

This is the printed data:

[image]

**Another way to do it is to loop through the columns and the rows:**

```
columns = len(df.columns)
rows = len(df)

for column in range(columns):
    print("-----------")
    for row in range(rows):
        print(df.loc[row][column])
```

[image]

Comment: This got me on track, I was able to apply this and manipulate it to fit what I was working on! Thank you!

Comment: @SublimizeD - welcome :) I am also studying pandas and numpy now :)